# What is the difference between Event grid trigger and http trigger?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-http-trigger

I am having difficulty in understanding the difference in both triggers

What is the difference between **EventGridTrigger** and **HTTP trigger**?

I just saw there is an option to filter events in  EventGridTrigger

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering

How we can filter events in the EventGridTrigger? Where should we add those filter options?

Comment: Hi, does my answer answered your question?

Comment: yes, almost it answered questions. Thank you so much @BowmanZhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event grid trigger is event-driven, it will be triggered when something you set happens. But Http trigger will be triggered when you send a request to hit it's endpoint.

For the filter of event grid trigger, you can go to this place:

[image]

(Click all service on Azure portal, click Event Grid Subscription, then find the Event Grid that you created, click in, you will find the Filters tab.)